# Migrating to Mercurial from SVN is not successful.Please read further for details

Tags: svn, mercurial, migration

I am trying to migrate a project from svn to mercurial. I am on ubuntu. In my /etc/mercurial/hgrc I added the following lines

```
[extensions]
hgext.convert =
```

Basically I am following the tutorial below:

```
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Convert+from+Subversion+to+Mercurial
```

After doing hg convert my-svn-local-repo my-local-mercurial-repoforsvn, hg converts the svn project (or so it seems). But when I browsed my-local-mercurial-repoforsvn there's only a .hg folder and nothing else.
According to the tutorial , there should be the whole project in my-local-mercurial-repoforsvn .

What is it that I am missing. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to the tutorial , there should be the whole project in my-local-mercurial-repoforsvn.

And it's here, but **only in repository** (.hg subdir) - `hg convert` does not update (and never update) working directory automatically. Un order to get sources in working directory, you must to run `hg up` in it